# extract specific string value from multiple columns with multiple patterns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've input table with mixed patterns (column values) and I'd like to extract the output as per the screenshot attached. Please find my query and help me out.

input table:

[image]

output table:

[image]

My query:

```sql
WITH _extract_franchise_code_challan_number
AS
(
    Select product_code
    ,ltrim(rtrim(fn1.value)) as value
    from [dbo].product 
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(franchise_code1,',') fn1 

    union

    Select product_code
    ,ltrim(rtrim(fn2.value)) as value
    from [dbo].product  
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(franchise_code2,',') fn2 

    union

    Select product_code
    ,ltrim(rtrim(fn3.value)) as value
    from [dbo].product 
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(franchise_code3,',') fn3 
)
Select product_code
,value as splited_data
,case when ltrim(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value))) like 'CH%' then ltrim(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)))
      else '' end as extracted_challan_number
,dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Substring(value, 1,Charindex(';', value)-1)) as franchise_code
,CASE WHEN dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Substring(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)), 1,Charindex('-', Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)))-1)) = '' THEN NULL ELSE dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Substring(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)), 1,Charindex('-', Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)))-1)) END as challan_from
,CASE WHEN dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Substring(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)), Charindex('-', Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)))+1, LEN(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value))))) = '' THEN NULL ELSE dbo.udf_GetNumeric(Substring(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)), Charindex('-', Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value)))+1, LEN(Substring(value, Charindex(';', value)+1, LEN(value))))) END as challan_to
from _extract_franchise_code_challan_number

WHERE value <>''
```

UDF function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetNumeric]
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intAlpha INT
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
END
END
RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
```

source data:

```
product_code | franchise_code1 | franchise_code2 | franchise_code3
```

---

```
32552  FC 19; CH 443358-, FC 22; CH 439031-, FC 25; CH 439031-,
FC 19; CH 443358-, FC 22; CH 439031-, FC 25; CH 439031-,NULL
```

---

```
32552 FC 35 FC 25; CH 51424-, FC 35; CH 55158-, FC 70; CH 51424- FC 21; CH 221073-, FC 22; CH 221090-
```

---

```
32552 RC10x51,42 FC 22; CH 171902-27000, FC 19; CH -27000, FC 25; CH -27000 NULL
```

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you. Take the time to post them in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statements but at least well formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: We also wouldn't be able to run your SQL even if we did have consumable data, as we don't have the definition of `dbo/udf_GetNumeric`.

Comment: If you can import image data so we can test it for your output

Comment: @meysam hello meysam, I've added the source data in text format.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following query

```
WITH _extract_franchise_code_challan_number
AS
(
Select product_code
    ,ltrim(rtrim(fn1.value)) as value
    from T16
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(franchise_code1,',') fn1 

    union

    Select product_code
    ,ltrim(rtrim(fn2.value)) as value
    from T16 
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(franchise_code2,',') fn2 

    union

    Select product_code
    ,ltrim(rtrim(fn3.value)) as value
    from T16
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(franchise_code3,',') fn3)
select product_code,
       franchise_code,
       case when challan_from = '' then NULL else challan_from end as challan_from,
       case when challan_to = '' then NULL else challan_to end as challan_to
from
(Select 
    product_code,
    Substring(value,4,2) as franchise_code,
    Replace(Substring(Substring(value,CHARINDEX(';',value) + 1,LEN(value)),0,CHARINDEX('-',Substring(value,CHARINDEX(';',value) + 1,LEN(value)))),'CH ','') as challan_from,
    Replace(Substring(Substring(value,CHARINDEX(';',value) + 1,LEN(value)),CHARINDEX('-',Substring(value,CHARINDEX(';',value) + 1,LEN(value))) + 1,LEN(value)),'FC ','') as challan_to
from _extract_franchise_code_challan_number
WHERE value <> '' AND CHARINDEX('-',Substring(value,CHARINDEX(';',value) + 1,LEN(value))) > 0) t
```

demo in [*dbfiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=366f2a73142db0aa45443023656f38b2)

Comment: Thanks meysam. I'm checking with multiple string patterns.